# My internet speed wont run at 1.0 Gbps on my Realtek PCIe Family Controller

Tags: windows-7, windows, network-adapter

I have an asus Gigabit Router and a gigabit NIC (Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller) witch is running at 100Mbps rather than 1000Mbps (1.0 Gbps).
When I use an old laptop on the same Ethernet cable(cat6) its running succesfully at 1.0 Gbps.
Means there's no problem with the setup, router nor the cable.
I tried changing the speed & duplex from auto negotiation to 1.0 Gbps but its still running at 100.0 Mbps.
I also have the latest driver update for my NIC.

I think im missing something but what ?
What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 5):

I have solved the issue by upgrading the driver.  The Realtek driver downloads can be found [here](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#1).

Comment: The link is to a page that allows you to download drivers. Don't know if there is a way to include that in the answer.

Comment: link is broken..!

Answer (score 4):

There are several different Realtek chips which identify themselves as ***Realtek PCIe Family Controller***. Although many of these chips support 1 Gigabit ethernet speeds, some do not, and there are new laptops sold, even now in 2017, with only a 100MB/s Realtek chip. Unfortunately, the HP Envy machine I got at Costco is one of them.

To check if your hardware supports 1 GB/s, go to the `properties` page for the `ethernet` adapter and `configure` the driver. On the `advanced` tab, select `speed & duplex` (you might have to scroll down in the list). Check the dropdown on the right to see if 1000 Mbps is listed.

If the chipset in the laptop does not support Gigabit ethernet, but has a **USB 3.0** port, then a workaround is to use a (e.g.) [USB 3.0 to 10/100/1000 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00M77HMU0).

Answer (score -1):

Can you verify the CAT6 cable used (are you sure it's not CAT5/CAT5E?) is wired the same each end ([check the colours on the underside of the RJ45's](https://www.brucetambling.com/w/images/c/c3/T568A_B.jpg)). Basically a CAT6 cable is a CAT5 cable with additional shielding.

If you had one end wired as T568A and the other as T568B then what you have is actually a 'cross-over' cable and not a 'patch cable'/'drop lead'. Originally intended for connecting 2 PC's together without a hub/switch the mistake is easy to make when wiring patch cables/wall sockets.

Which model NIC Realtek PCIe GBE do you have?

Comment: I have both side wired as T568B and when i use my old laptop it work fine ..so the cable may not be a problem ..I have RTL8167 driver version 7.65.1025.2012

Comment: [This](http://www.realtek.com.tw/DOWNLOADS/RedirectFTPSite.aspx?SiteID=4&DownTypeID=3&DownID=800&PFid=5&Conn=4&FTPPath=ftp%3a%2f%2f95.130.192.218%2fcn%2fnic%2fInstall_Win7_7065_11232012.zip) is the driver package I would use (from [Realtek](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false) site, totally untested).

Comment: [Here](http://www.w7forums.com/realtek-onboard-lan-doesnt-work-above-10-mbps-t9501.html) and [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/realtek-onboard-lan-doesnt-work-above-10-mbps-t4031195.html) are users with similar issues, but with onboard NICs. Try some of the recommendations. The main one being - power down for at least 15 mins before rebooting.

Comment: i tried and doesnt work for me

Comment: My next step would be to use a 'Linux live CD' to test the hardware.

Comment: Shielding has nothing to do with it... you can get shielded or unshielded cat5 or cat6 ( unshielded is most common ).  The difference is the characteristic impedance.  Also if it were a crossover cable, it would not limit the speed.  Either it would work fine ( because at least one end has automatical polarity detection and reversal ) or not at all.